# Extract keys from map in a data type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to return keys with a certain `Status` in a data type with many fields. I tried a few things, but nothing is even compiling! Anyone got a tip I could use?

```
data Configuration v = Configuration {
configurationMap   :: Map.Map v Status,
configurationGraph :: Graph v
}

verticesByStatus :: Ord v => Status -> Configuration v -> [v]
verticesByStatus  ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to express this, but here is one solution:

```
  verticesByStatus status (Configuration map graph) = fst <$> (filter ((== status) . snd) $ M.assocs map)
```

So what's happening here? First, we pattern match on the configuration parameter to extract it's two components and assign them to variables `map` and `graph`. Now let's break down the right hand side:

```
  fst <$> (filter ((== status) . snd) $ Map.assocs map)
                                            ^-- This comes from the Data.Map package and splits a map into a list of tuples of key/value pairs. 
                            ^-- Here, we filter our new list of key/values based on the values, and find only those that match the input status 
  ^-- Last, we fmap the function fst over the whole list to extract only the keys that match your given status
```

Another way to express this function, would be to simplify it through eta-reduction. One way to do that would be to use the `configurationMap` function to extract that portion of your configuration instead of pattern matching:

```
  verticesByStatus status = fmap fst . filter ((== status) . snd) . Map.assocs . configurationMap
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  your answer was complete!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:filter) for maps in `Data.Map`, which can be used directly with your configuration map:

```
verticesByStatus :: Ord v => Status -> Configuration v -> [v]
verticesByStatus status = Map.keys . Map.filter (== status) . configurationMap
```

[`Map.keys`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:keys) produces a list of the keys in the map. (If you wanted a list of values instead, you might use `Map.elems` or, equivalently, `toList` from `Data.Foldable`. Note that, somewhat confusingly, the latter isn't the same as `Map.toList`, which produces a list of key-value pairs, just like `Map.assocs` in jkeuhlen's answer.)

Comment: I like your approch, how would you deal with  updateStatus :: Ord v => v -> Status -> Configuration v -> Configuration v

Comment: @Phil With [`Map.adjust`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:adjust): `updateStatus key status config = config { configurationMap = Map.adjust (const status) key (configurationMap config) }`. Here, `const status` is just a tidy way of writing `(\_ -> status)`. Note that using [`Map.insert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:insert) would be simpler, but it would insert keys in the map if they didn't exist beforehand, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
verticesByStatus :: Ord v => Status -> Configuration v -> [v]
verticesByStatus status (Configuration cMap cGraph) =
    [ v
    | v <- vertices cGraph,
      Just(status) == (Map.lookup v cMap)]
```

A few notes:

- I would opt for avoiding `Map.assocs` because it costs an extra O(n) to run and you can get at the values in your config map without first converting it to a list of tuples (see the [Map docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html%20docs)).
- I opted for a list comprehension instead of combining `map` and `filter` out of personal preference since I find it easier to read (something I picked up after reading [this article](https://blog.infinitenegativeutility.com/2017/12/some-notes-about-how-i-write-haskell))
- We could have instead checked if the lookup returned a `Just` or a `Nothing` and then extracted the value in the case of a `Just` using `fromJust` but that would be more code and probably harder to read. It would look something like:

  ```
  verticesByStatus :: Ord v => Status -> Configuration v -> [v]
  verticesByStatus status (Configuration cMap cGraph) =
      [ v
      | v <- vertices cGraph,
        let vStatus = Map.lookup v cMap,
        if (isJust vStatus) then (status == (fromJust vStatus)) else False]
  ```

Comment: Posted right after @duplode - I would go with their solution.

Comment: On `isJust`/`fromJust`, indeed there almost always is a nicer solution than squeezing a `Maybe` into a boolean only to have to rely on the partial `fromJust` to ultimately handle it. Pattern matching (as in your preferred solution) is an improvement (it is worth noting how the list comprehension silently handles the `Nothing` case here); another possibility would be using the `maybe` function instead of the if-then-else in your second solution: `maybe False (== status) vStatus`

Comment: Awesome @duplode! I wasn't aware of the `maybe` function.